# Comparing strings with JSTL

Tags: java, jsf, jstl

I have two strings that  i need to compare, but even if they have the same values or different , it *always* enters the   statement...

```
<c:when test="#{bean.name1 != bean.name2}">
     fields that are supposed to appear _only_ when name1 is different from name2
</c:when>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is that you probably did not wrap the when in a choose tag.

if you have:

```
    <c:choose>
    <c:when test="${bean.name1 != bean.name2}">
        fields that are supposed to appear _only_ when name1 is different from name2
    </c:when>
</c:choose>
```

It will work

Answer (score 4):

Should it be ?

```
<c:if test="#{bean.name1 != bean.name2}">
     // code
</c:if>
```

EDIT :  `<c:when>` is supposed to be inside `<c:choose>`. Cannot ask why, that is just the syntax. It is like asking why `if` will not work in place of `switch` in C/C++/Java. They are just different animals.

Comment: Not if its wrapped in a <c:choose> tag

Comment: # is also valid if using facelets.

Answer (score 0):

Does it make any difference if you do this:

```
<c:when test="${bean.name1 != bean.name2}">
     fields that are supposed to appear _only_ when name1 is different from name2
</c:when>
```

Comment: yes, i tried this, and it has the same result. I changed it to c:If and now it worked. But i did not understand why it did not work with c:When...

Answer (score 0):

I have noticed some flakiness when using c:if or c:choose and c:when inside some jsf iteration components, such as rich:datatable. What is the full context?

As a workaround, I would commonly have to wrap things in an a4j:outputPanel and set the rendered attribute accordingly.

Answer (score -1):

Try this...

```
<c:if test="${bean.name1 ne bean.name2}">
     fields that are supposed to appear _only_ when name1 is different from name2
</c:if>
```

ne = not equal

Also

# should be $

Comment: Hi, i tried with $ but it does work. i had to change to the C:IF tag. Thanks.

Comment: cool ok, just realised it should be c:if too - i didn't understand your original question

Answer (score -1):

Should it be 
    
         fields that are supposed to appear *only* when name1 is different from name2

Comment: yes, the fields should appear only when they are different. The problem is that even if they have the same values, it enters the <c:when> statement, but it was not supposed to.

Comment: I also tried to do this  <c:when test="#{not (bean.name1 eq bean.name2) }">  but it is the same result.